# Difficulty in arranging plots

Tags: ggplot2, plot, cowplot, patchwork

I have total 7 plots. 
Six of them are line charts which are to be aligned and arranged one below each other such that there is no space between them - to make one composite plot.

Here is the data and ggplot2 code and I am using the same line chart 6 times just to explain my problem

```
x<- 1:10

y<- rnorm(10)

data <- data.frame(x,y)


library(ggplot2)
k<- ggplot(data, aes(x= x, y= y)) + geom_line() +  theme(panel.background=element_blank()) + theme(aspect.ratio = 0.15) + theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "black", size= 0.5), axis.line.y = element_line(colour = "black", size= 0.5), axis.ticks.y = element_line(colour = "black", size= 0.5), axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) + xlab(label = "")+ ylab(label = "") + scale_x_continuous(label= NULL) +theme(plot.margin = unit(c(-0.25, 2, -0.25, 2), "cm"))
k
```

Seventh is scatter plot with regression line

```
a<- 1:10
a

b<- 11:20
b

data1 <- data.frame(a,b)
data1

library(ggplot2)
k3<-ggplot(data1, aes(x=a, y=b))+ geom_point(shape=1, fill ="black", alpha= 1, color= "black", size=3) + geom_smooth(method = lm, size = 0.5, linetype ="dotted", fill ="black", color= "black", alpha = 0.3)
k3

k3<- k3 + expand_limits(x = c(0.5, 10.5), y = c(10.5,20.5)) +  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = c(2,4, 6, 8, 10)) + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),breaks = c(10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20)) 
k3

k3 <- k3 +  theme(panel.background=element_blank())+ theme(aspect.ratio = 1) + theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "black"), axis.line.y = element_line(colour = "black", size= 0.5), axis.ticks.y = element_line(colour = "black", size= 0.5), axis.ticks.x = element_line(colour = "black", size= 0.5)) 
k3

k3<- k3 + scale_x_reverse(expand = c(0, 0)) 
k3

#Flip axes 
k3<- k3 + coord_flip() 
k3<- k3 + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "cm"))
k3
```

I want to arrange (1) composite plot (on left) and (2) scatter plot (on right)side by side. So I tried arranging that way using (1) ggarrange() [in ggpubr] and (2) plot_grid()[in cowplot], but I couldn't.

Could anybody help? Thankyou!

I want the layout to look like this

[image: layout]

Comment: I've tried your code and the results look identical. Maybe you should update packages? Why don't you just use `ggarrange`?

Comment: Thank you! I updated packages, but unfortunately now ggarrange is also not working. what could be going wrong?

Comment: What machine do you running (Win, Linux or Mac)? Try to update R also and restart R, PC etc.

Comment: I had tried updating R and restarting R and  PC (Win 10) as well. I have latest version of R ( 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) -- "Holding the Windsock"), so I believe that is not the issue. Hope, 'ggarrange' not working is some trivial issue and will  be solved. But my main problem is arranging more plots. Let me edit my question, could you please have a look? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really hope, that I've understand you correctly. To be honest your code is a mess, so I was using a default `iris` dataset.

The hint is to use `plot_grid` twice:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

k <- iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank())

k3 <- iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  theme_classic()

grid1 <- cowplot::plot_grid(
  k, k, k, k, k, k,
  ncol = 1,
  align = "hv"
)

cowplot::plot_grid(grid1, k3, 
                   align = "hv",
                   rel_widths = c(1.5, 1), # you can control the relative width and height
                   nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @atsyplenkov for your time and efforts! Your solution is very helpful. I tried it, it is working but the (1) composite plot of line charts and (2) scatter plot are not exactly aligned along bottom and top axis. Scatter plot is at little lower level relative to composite plot (despite align = "hv" ). Wonder if there is any way to achieve that? Now I have also edited the layout image to explain that part in my question. Thank you!

Comment: Yeap, I've also found out this. I'll think

Answer (score 1):

Found solution! Got desired result with package 'patchwork' in combination with some changes in plot margins.

Here is the code and result

```
library(ggplot2)

iris 

# Line charts 
k <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(-0.25,-3,-0.25,0), "cm")) + 
  theme(aspect.ratio = 0.15)

# Line chart (k4) with y-axis label
k4 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(
    vjust = 2,
    color = "black",
    size = 10,
    face = "bold"
  ))+ 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(-0.25,-3,-0.25,0), "cm"))+ 
  theme(aspect.ratio = 0.15)

# scatter plot
sc <-ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  theme_classic()+
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,-0.5), "cm"))+
  theme(aspect.ratio = 0.7) 
sc

library(patchwork)

p<- (k/k/k/k4/k/k)| sc
p
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Well done! I think that changes in `plot.margin` have played a key role.